# Countdown time for specified condition on div on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using  similar countdown on particular by counting 3.49minutes . However the problem is the countdown span are totally different with the similar countdown that i did as i need to implement the same function for this particular time and match each other time. Sorry if my explanation not clear enough.

HTML:

```
<div class="clock cl-count"> 
                      <b class="clock_b0">00</b> 
                      <b class="clock_b1">03</b> 
                      <b class="clock_b2">49</b> 
                      <span class="s"></span>
                  </div>
```

Above of this are working by getting time from that javascript i did.

```
<dd class="sortableitem on" data-lt-cls="ssc" data-default="3" data-lt="CQSSC">
                  <div><em>重庆时时彩</em><span countdown="1">03:49</span>
                  </div>
               </dd>
```

The question is how to we implement the same function to get the countdown for above this ? without changing the div

my working Jquery for the first section Code :

```
var secondSum = 230;
            var time = setInterval(function(){
                secondSum--;
                if(secondSum == 0){
                    secondSum = 230;
                }
                var minute = parseInt(secondSum/60);
                var second = secondSum - minute*60;
                $('.clock_b1').html("0" + minute);
                $('.clock_b2').html(second>9?second:"0"+second);
            }, 1000)
```

Comment: Sorry, your explanation isn't clear enough what you trying to achieve here.

Comment: @RandikaRatnayake i want to make the both div of the countdown by getting the same countdown time

Comment: Could you show the working javascript for the first code section, maybe that would help to explain your issue better.

Comment: @Exception_al Hi , i have include the first code section for the particular working javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var secondSum = 230;
            var time = setInterval(function(){
                secondSum--;
                if(secondSum == 0){
                    secondSum = 230;
                }
                var minute = parseInt(secondSum/60);
                var second = secondSum - minute*60;
                
                
                $("#countdown1").text("0"+minute+":"+ (second>9?second:"0"+second));
                
            }, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
                  
                  <dd class="sortableitem on" data-lt-cls="ssc" data-default="3" data-lt="CQSSC">
                  <div><em>重庆时时彩 </em><span id="countdown1" countdown="1">03:49</span>
                  </div>
               </dd>
```

Comment: Thanks raj its really working, this is what i want :)

Comment: $('dd div span').text("0" + minute + ":" + (second > 9 ? second : "0" + second)); May be this would fix the missing 0 for seconds :)

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL is that possible we only set for this particular <div><em>重庆时时彩</em><span countdown="1">03:49</span></div> on countdown as i implement your code , it will run all of the div that has countdown time

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL i mean if the name of em == 重庆时时彩 then only will run the countdown?

Comment: @MorganNg OK check now I have add id to span tag and change in JS

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL Thanks alot , its was perfect :D

Comment: @MorganNg Welcome brother Once again .. !